# Kubernetes pod definition file issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, wso2-esb

I can run the Docker container for wso2 ei with following command.

```
docker run -it -p 8280:8280 -p 8243:8243 -p 9443:9443 -v wso2ei:/home/wso2carbon --name integrator wso2/wso2ei-integrator
```

I'm trying to create the pod definition file for the same. I don't know how to do port mapping and volume mapping in pod definition file. The following is the file I have created up to now. How can I complete the rest?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: ei-pod
    labels:
        type: ei
        version: 6.6.0
spec:
    containers:
        - name: integrator
          image: wso2/wso2ei-integrator
```

Comment: have u looked at the kubernetes documentation?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu: Yes, couldn't find a good resource. Highly appreciate if you can point to a good resource.

Comment: In the official Kubernetes documentation, [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) are good starting points.  Better still is if you can arrange to store data outside the pod itself.  Generally running a Deployment (or a StatefulSet) will work better than running a bare Pod, if nothing else because you can change things like the `image:` and have the cluster restart the Pod for you.

Comment: What is "wso2 ei"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: WSO2 is a product company. EI stands for Enterprise Integrator, which is an ESB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is YAML content which might work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ei-pod
  labels:
    type: ei
    version: 6.6.0
spec:
  containers:
  - name: integrator
    image: wso2/wso2ei-integrator
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8280
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /wso2carbon
      name: wso2ei
  volumes:
  - name: wso2ei
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /home/wso2carbon
```

While the above YAML content is just a basic example, it's not recommended for production usage because of two reasons:

1. Use deployment or statefulset or daemonset instead of pods directly.
2. `hostPath` volume is not sharable between nodes. So use external volumes such as NFS or Block and mount it into the pod. Also look at dynamic volume provisioning using storage class.

Comment: `hostPath:` type volumes will resolve to a different place on each node; they do not refer to shared content.  I'd only use them in fairly specialized circumstances, like a DaemonSet that does log management.

Comment: @DavidMaze: So, if I have to make some configuration changes to each pod, how can I achieve it?